# Segmentation fault on std::string in Openwrt (Designated Driver) running on Netgear R7500

Tags: c++, eclipse, protocol-buffers, openwrt

I am running a simple client server program using ZMQ and Protobuf. The server part is cross compiled (in eclipse Mars) using the Openwrt toolchain present in this. https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ipq806x/generic/

The server program runs perfectly fine on Netgear R7500 router if std::string function is not used. And results in segmentation fault if used.

Server:

```
try {
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t request;
        //  Wait for next request from client
        int recv = socket.recv(&request);
        assert(recv == 1);
        std::cout << "Received" << std::endl;
        Nodeinfo node;
        std::cout << "size of message is " << request.size() << std::endl;
        bool parsed = node.ParseFromArray(request.data(), request.size());

    /*  std::string text_str; 
        google::protobuf::TextFormat::PrintToString(node, &text_str);
        std::cout << text_str << std::endl;*/ --> commented code results in segfault

        if (parsed == 1) {
            std::cout << "Parsed successfully" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Node info received for MAC Address "
                    << node.macaddress().c_str() << std::endl;
            socket.send("Nodeinfo received successfully", 0);
        }

    }
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << " caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;

}
return 0;
```

Initially the std::string was underlined in red in eclipse as it was not able to identify the right include file. However it was getting compiled. After some research , I took a suggestion from this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353719#c5 and did an index rebuild on the project which eliminated the red line. Still I continued to get segmentation fault on server. Char* does work, however I need std::string to work with protobuf.

Client:

```
try {
    Nodeinfo node;
    node.set_bandwidth("25Mbps");
    node.set_location("50°40'46,461\"N 95°48'26,533\"W 123,45m");
    node.set_uptime_secs(30000);
    node.set_ram(2);
    node.set_processing_power("Intel(R)Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU@3.40 GHz");
    node.set_timestamp("2016-19-07T20:00:00");
    node.set_location_accuracy(2);
    node.set_macaddress("54:ee:75:4d:ae:3d");

    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);

    std::cout << "Connecting to server" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://192.168.1.2:5555");

    zmq::message_t request (node.ByteSize());
    zmq::message_t reply;

    node.SerializeToArray(request.data(),request.size());
    std::cout << "Sending Nodeinfo..." << std::endl;
    std::string text_str;
    google::protobuf::TextFormat::PrintToString(node, &text_str);
    std::cout << text_str << std::endl;
    socket.send (request);
    socket.recv(&reply);
    std::cout << "Nodeinfo received successfully!" << std::endl;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << " caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;

}

// Optional:  Delete all global objects allocated by libprotobuf.
google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
return 0;
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the prototype to `PrintToString`.  A `std::string` is not a `char *`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I found at `static bool PrintToString(const Message & message, string * output)` at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format

Comment: Not sure it is right as the OP has a `NodeInfo` and this wants a `Message`.

Comment: @Nathan I'd suspect `Nodinfo` derives from `Message` as it was generated by the protobuf compiler.

Comment: `Char* does work,` -- Then assuming it is a `std::string* that this function requires`, there is no way that passing a `char *` to this function will work without a memory overrun and / or undefined behavior occurring.  If that function is located in a DLL or external library, then a probable reason for the crash is that the `std::string` you're passing is not compatible with the `std::string` being used in the external module.

Comment: Yes the Nodeinfo is message and generated by protobuf compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : I should have been clearer in mentioning that char* test = "something" prints but not std::string test = "something". The protobuf textformat PrintToString does not work with char*.

Comment: Try using `Print(node, std::cout)` instead. It seems unlikely that the program would crash because of `std::string`. Did you also try doing something like `std::string test("test"); cout << test << "\n" ?

Comment: @kixorz I tried using Print which resulted in error "error: no matching function for call to 'google::protobuf::TextFormat::Print(Nodeinfo&, std::ostream&)". The print function of Protobuf works with ZeroCopyOutputStream(https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format) which I guess is not same as standard output stream. And yes, I have tried with std::string test("test"), it still results in segfault.

Comment: @DishaBhat looks like your standard library has problems, did you try reinstalling `libstdc++` or using different compiler?

Comment: @kixorz : On Openwrt I guess I have the right libstdc++(libstdc++.so.6), if not would just(only) std::string give an issue?

Comment: @DishaBhat Not sure, why it would be a problem. Did you try basic HelloWorld with `std::string` and `cout`?

Comment: @kixorz The basic Helloworld with std::string works perfectly fine. But the same thing in this program doesn't work! That's bizarre.  I have z, zmq, protobuf and uClibc++ libraries included in the Cross G++ linker and the library path is given from toolchain's staging_dir target's usr/lib folder. And include path is from the same path usr/include. Am I missing something obvious??